# i want to do some css styling with label and span when select option is anything but disabled or an option is just selected

Tags: html, css, dropdown, html-select

i want to style label::after and span inside the label when one of the options is selected that is except for default one.

```
      <div class="drop">
        <select name="years">
          <option disabled selected>choose one</option>
          <option>less than 2 years</option>
          <option>more than 2 but less than 5 years</option>
          <option>more than 5 but less than 10 years </option>
          <option>more than 10 years</option>
        </select>
        <label class="label">
          <span class="span">experience</span>
        </label>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a listener to select changes
2. if option index !=0 proceed
3. add class selector `className` to the label element

Add `.className::after` and `.className span` selectors with your desired styles into your css. Remember to remove these class when option 0 is selected again...